# Distances between successive points - Statistical Test

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have a set of experimental data which comprises distances between successive points:

[image]

I also have a set of similar data that has been generated by a model that attempts to recapture the (biological) phenomenon behind the experimental distances.

An example of each set is here:

[image]

```
x-axis = No. of Distances (plotted in increasing size)
y-axis (logarithmic) = Distance size
```

I am not an accomplish statistician and was wondering what the best statistical test or approach would be to use in order to assess the agreement between these two sets of data? I effectively want to know how well the model recaptures the experimental data - the "closeness" of the data/fit.

**EDIT:** The most important parts of the data typically reside at the tails any test needs to be somewhat sensitive to this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your graph is essentially [Ripley's K](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~dipankar/pubh8472/RipleysK.pdf) function, just without dividing by the density of the point pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various statistical tests you can do to check for agreement between distributions.  One test is known as the two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which compares the empirical distribution functions of the two samples.  The test statistic takes the form,

$$
\sup_{s \in \mathbb{R}} \left | \hat{F}_1(s) - \hat{F}_2(s) \right | ,
$$

where if your two samples are $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n_1})$ and $(y_1, y_2, \ldots , y_{n_2})$ we define $\hat{F}_1(s) \equiv n^{-1}_1 \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} I(x_{i} \leq s)$ and $\hat{F}_2(s) \equiv n^{-1}_2 \sum_{i=1}^{n_2} I(y_{i} \leq s)$.  So, each function tells what proportion of the sample is less than or equal to any value $s \in \mathbb{R}$, and then you calculate the largest difference between these functions.  When this distance is large you conclude that the true distributions differ, and what constitutes "large" depends on how this value behaves when the distributions are in fact the same.  Most statistical software packages will have a procedure for performing this test for you, so you shouldn't have to worry too much about these details.  Do you have access to something like R or SAS?  It may even be possible to run in Excel.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a useful test. I primarily use MATLAB rather than R or SAS but this seems capable of performing the test: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html#btn1_1d-1 - the test returns three variables (h) - a decision to reject the null hypothesis, (p) - the asymptotic p-value (the closer to 1.0 this is, the highest the agreement of the data?) and k - the test statistic for the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov - what is this describing?

Comment: My data often has variation in the tails - and the tails are rather important to the conclusions being drawn. Is there a modified form of the KS-test that is more sensitive to variation at the tails?

Comment: It does seem that there is a "weighted" KS test (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7308v2.pdf) but I've never used it myself.  One solution might be to just truncate the distribution looking only at the tail and then apply a standard unweighted KS test.

Comment: Thanks. I did not consider doing that. I have come across the Anderson-Darling test - is this appropriate to my problem? It appears to be a modified KS-test that is more sensitive to deviation at the tails.

Comment: I think the Anderson-Darling test is usually thought of as a one sample test, but I suppose it could be adapted to two samples.  It does involve a weight function $w(x)$ which allows you to assign more weight to the tail if you wish, although then you have to think about how to define this function.  I personally haven't used this test so can't really comment too much on it.